# How to return an image without closing the Lambda request?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python 3.6 code in AWS Lambda that opens a website using selenium and chrome driver. It opens the page then takes a screenshot of it and returns the Base64 string to my local PC that then saves it as a .PNG file. Is it possible to return this image without stopping the lambda code. I'm trying to see all the Web-pages it goes thru one at a time.

The lambda_function.py looks like this right now.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    print("Starting Chrome")
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1696')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/user-data')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-logging')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--log-level=0')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--v=99')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--single-process')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--data-path=/tmp/data-path')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--homedir=/tmp')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disk-cache-dir=/tmp/cache-dir')
    chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36')
    chrome_options.binary_location = os.getcwd() + "/bin/headless-chromium"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    png = ""
    if 'url' in event.keys():
        driver.get(event['url'])
        # take first screenshot here
        # png = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        try:
            send = driver.find_element_by_id("action-button")
            send.click()
            time.sleep(4)
            # take second screenshot here
            # png = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            return "action-button not found"
        time.sleep(15)
        png = driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()
    driver.close()
    return png
```

I would like to just be able to view each page as they load on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by having the Lambda send the image result for each page to your email through [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/), or uploading the image to [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and then sending the link to the object to your email/phone/etc. through [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/).

All these services have [well documented SDKs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/index.html)

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you so much. Did not even think of this possibility :)

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to select this answer using the checkmark option (and upvote if you wish) so that this question gets marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

No. The `return` statement ends execution of the Lambda function.

While Python does have a `yield` command that halts execution until the next iterable is requested, it is not applicable for Lambda.

You could monitor the Lambda function via log output in CloudWatch Logs, but there is a bit of a delay before the log entry is accessible.

Comment: I had a feeling that would be the case. Thought maybe someone knew something about lambda that's not really talked about that could help. Thank you for confirming tho :) much appreciated!